как прописать пайплайн чтоб ранеры сразу связывались с контейнером в докер-хабе? делаю это всё в гитлабе
потому что получается по моей логике он связывается с докер-демоном, но выдает ошибку что нельзя к нему подключиться, я просто такой пример нашёл где-то , не знаю как иначе
вот сам скрипт
stages:


- build
  - test
  - deploy

build_image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: docker
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""  # Отключение TLS, если вы используете порт 2375
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"  # Указание адреса для Docker Daemon
  script:
    - echo "Проверка версии Docker CLI..."
    - docker --version
    
    - echo "Проверка переменной DOCKER_HOST..."
    - echo "DOCKER_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST"
    
    - echo "Проверка подключения к Docker Daemon..."
    - curl -v $DOCKER_HOST/v1.41/info || echo "Не удалось подключиться к Docker Daemon"

    - echo "Проверка состояния Docker Daemon в DinD..."
    - docker info || echo "Не удалось получить информацию о Docker Daemon"
    
    - echo "Проверка запущенных контейнеров Docker..."
    - docker ps || echo "Не удалось получить список запущенных контейнеров"

    # Вход в Docker Hub
    - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin || echo "Не удалось войти в Docker Hub"
    
    # Построение и публикация Docker образа
    - docker build -t my-image:latest . || echo "Не удалось собрать Docker образ"
    - docker tag my-image:latest $DOCKER_USERNAME/my-image:latest || echo "Не удалось тегировать Docker образ"
    - docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/my-image:latest || echo "Не удалось опубликовать Docker образ"

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Running tests..."

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploying..."


Как вы запускаете раннер? В докере или в ОС? Если в ОС, то у пользователя, от имени которого запущен раннер, должен быть доступ к /var/run/docker.sock - для этого достаточно добавить пользователя, от чьего имени запущен раннер, в группу docker. Если раннер запущен в докере, то нужно при запуске контейнера отмапить хостовый /var/run/docker.sock на /var/run/docker.sock  в контейнере.
